# Link doesn't work properly after deploying site on firebase

Tags: html, firebase, firebase-hosting

I have a problem with my website after deploying it through firebase. I have a link in my navigation that takes me to my home page. This link takes me however to the 404 page. All other links work properly.
This is the website: https://investmentreports-e9ecb.firebaseapp.com/

P.S. the link to the index page is hidden in the logo.

Comment: Can you show us your code please ?

Comment: Hello Val, this is the code from the nav:

Comment: <nav>
        
    <div class="toggle">
    <i class="fas fa-bars menu"></i>
    </div>    
    <ul>
 
<li><a href="index.html"><img src="images/logo-transp.png"></a></li>         

      
                
    </ul>
    
    </nav>

Comment: url getting `public` only from about page

Answer (score 2):

In about page anchor contain `public` that why getting `404`


[image]


Just remove `.../public` in about page header

All other pages header have just index.html

 Happy coding...!